# How to load user controls dynamically in ASP.NET without postback

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, controls, postback

I have a ASP.Net(C#) page. When a user selects a value in dropdownlist, some new controls will be visible to him.

I am able to that now, but the page has to reload every time and state has to be maintained between postbacks.

Is there any way to do the same without reloading of the page in a easiest way possible without using ajax control toolkit?

**Additional info**: the data for the dropdownlist is coming from the database, and some places it has to be all server side so i can't use javascript .

Comment: You need post back for sure. Why can't you use Ajax?

Comment: Do you know it advance what the controls will be and how many? Could you create them all, with visibility = false and then unhide them client side when the dropdown changes?

Comment: Have you tried exploring the `UpdatePanel` and all the asp.net goodness for this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Winks : i am doing similar but in my case datasource binding and visibility=true is happing on the event handler of the previous control.

Comment: I am not clear with your question

Answer (score 0):

You can try this idea: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208(v=vs.100).aspx. I have not try it before but it seems logical.

Answer (score 0):

you should go through updatepanel. Put all the controls inside a updatepanel which you want to show on selectedindexchanged event of the dropdownlist and write code behind on selectedindexchanged event of the dropdownlist accordingly. Hope this will help you...